# create a new class instance in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I know that these two scripts are correct and are identical but I need to know what is the most used:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {}
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();
```

and

```
var Emitter = require('events');

var emtr = new Emitter();
```

Comment: They're not identical? And empty classes hardly ever make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theyre not that equal. With the first one you can easily override properties:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  test(){
    console.log("test");
  }
}
var instance=new MyEmitter();
```

While the second:

```
var Emitter = require('events');
var emtr = new Emitter();
emtr.test=_=>console.log("test");
var instance=Object.create(emtr);
emtr.constructor.call(instance);
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, but in the 2 scripti can calling the 'on' method that is defined in 'events' class.  So the second also can inherited methods from 'events' .

Comment: @MohamedBenHENDA didnt say the opposite. The first one is much easier concerning  overriding / extending